# Should I build a second site just like the first but with a different keyword to rank for a synonym?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, local-seo, localization

I have a listing site which lists freelancers in a very specific profession. In my site each place (city or so...) is a separated page. and it is focused on this profession keyword with the place name.

So for example let's say this site profession is "plumber״ so each page on the site will have to focus on a keyword in the formate of "plumber in tel-aviv" or "plumber in haifa" and so on...

That works great and I'm in the first position on Google.

**The problem is:**
This profession name has two words in my language, and the amount of searches per month is the same for those two words. so how can I target those both without losing the power of focusing my site only on one keyword (which totally works for me).

One way I thought of is just add another site which focuses on the other word but using the same database of the first one. just changing every instance of the first word to the second word.

Comment: You do not give us the terms so it really is impossible to give advice. Going off of your title, if the two terms are synonyms, then the language ontologies handle this for you and trying to rank a site for each term clearly would not make sense. I am NOT a believer in having multiple sites for one business. To me, it is a symptom of not knowing how to properly set up a site. One site should be able to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Google understand user intent many times, for example.

1. how to make bootable pendrive.
2. how to make bootable flash drive.

Return same results, but sometimes they don't understand user intent on many queries. So If you think your both query return different result, then feel free to create a new website. I would defenetly create a new website if I don't see my site on first page with slightly variant keywords.

But I will prefer different styles, different navigation, different google search console account etc.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. but my question is for the second situation (different results) and the different styles, nav... is not an option for me. what i can do id only have same site - changing only this specific word (the reason for that is that I'm asking for one site but actually i have a lost of different profession sites and i need some "automatic" solution and not a "custom made" solution. so I'm still interested to know taking those details to account if this will be the right solution and if it wouldn't have bad SEO effects.

Comment: If you just change only keywords and rest of sites are whole same, then G will not going to display two results from your two different website, because they know you own all websites. For example If I am ranking for XYZ product review on my domain1.com and I write different things for XYZ product review on domain2.com, then G will not going to rank my both website. Your profession are clean but think about insurance, don't you think company also want to see their top 3 results, because they are getting very good ROI compare to cost(to run different site).

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question. we are talking here about one site ranking on XYZ and one site ranking on YXZ not on two sites ranking on the same keyword. what i plane to change is the keyword itself and not the other content.

Comment: I said domain1.com and domain2.com, please read comment again, I'm talking about two different website from begin. If you just replace XYZ to YXZ on second domain, but whole site structure is same, then you will not going to rank both website, because Google think it is same website own by same guy. Don't think only about your site, there are many insurance sites as well, if Google rank them like that, then everybody want to see their 3 results from their different domain. [Read section 2.1](https://goo.gl/c4KF85) from this doc, you might get some idea, why it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Google usually handles synonyms automatically these days.   At most you would just need to use the synonym sometimes on the same site.

Google calls copying pages and just changing one keyword [doorway pages](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721311?hl=en) and it can penalize sites that do that.