# How do you rank in Google for synonyms while using the professional industry preferred term?

Tags: seo, search-terms

For a site I'm currently working on related to the automobile industry.  I need to get the SEO optimized. The subject has many different synonyms. For professionalism we only use one term.

How can I make the site findable for all the terms that are related? When I search for them currently, I only get unrelated sites.  I would like to influence Google to make sure the synonyms are working too.

For example: multi-cab, cruisecab which in Dutch is dubbele cabine, grijskenteken toepassingen. (and many several gramatical variations).

Comment: For SEO in multiple languages you still need to have a different URL for every language.  See [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

Comment: For improving rankings (including synonyms) see: [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

Comment: Thanks for you answers so far. I have edited to limit it to the general terms only. From your link provided I don't see the instruction for synonyms, by search or by looking at the top-answer in detail. Am I missing something?

Comment: There is also this question: [Should I build a second site just like the first but with a different keyword to rank for a synonym?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/108601/should-i-build-a-second-site-just-like-the-first-but-with-a-different-keyword-to)